# Make a list from multiple list

Tags: python, list

I have three lists:

```
list_01 = ['DOG','CAT','BEAR']
list_02 = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']
list_03 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
```

What I hope to get is a list like the following:

```
list_04 = ['DOG','V','A','CAT','W','B','BEAR','X','C','Y','D','Z','E','F','G','H']
```

This list is supposed to contain one item from list 1, then one from list 2, and one from list 3. This then continues until list 1 is exhausted; list 1 should then be ignored, and the same process should happen on just lists 2 and 3, continuing until all lists are empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you want to do this in order, not randomly. If so, you can use [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools and make a nested list comprehension:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_01 = ['DOG','CAT','BEAR']
list_02 = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']
list_03 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']


list_04 = [n for group in zip_longest(list_01, list_02, list_03) 
           for n in group if n is not None]

# ['DOG', 'V', 'A', 'CAT', 'W', 'B', 'BEAR', 'X', 'C', 'Y', 'D', 'Z', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

Note: `zip_longest` will produce `None` values when one list runs out. That's why we are filtering for `None` in the comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `zip_longest` and `chain` from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html) module:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
list_04 = [i for i in chain(*zip_longest(list_01, list_02, list_03))
           if i is not None]
```

output:

```
['DOG', 'V', 'A', 'CAT', 'W', 'B', 'BEAR', 'X', 'C', 'Y', 'D', 'Z', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

Comment: This will remove all falsy values, not just None, which might be a problem for OP.

Comment: @AKX I have seen you interesting alternative. I tend not to optimize prematurely, OP's example seem to indicate that no falsy values are expected ;)

Comment: BTW how to handle cases when one of list contain None?

Comment: @eroot163pi You can use `fillvalue=XXX` in `zip_longest` with something that you know won't match and test equality with that instead.

Comment: @eroot163pi check the iterator of AKX, this is what it does

Comment: @eroot163pi *"it is difficult to construct an element not in the list"* - Nah, it's trivial, usually done with `object()`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```
result = list(roundrobin(list_01, list_02, list_03))
```

Just copy&paste `roundrobin` from the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) or import it [from more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin) (as mentioned by the recipes section).

---

Alternatively, I like using `heapq.merge`:

```
result = list(map(itemgetter(1), merge(*map(enumerate, lists), key=itemgetter(0))))
```

Variant:

```
index, value = map(itemgetter, (0, 1))
result = list(map(value, merge(*map(enumerate, lists), key=index)))
```

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDNTsMwEITvfgrf4iIfkubCJYfQFLghIUT5EaoiWFqLODbOBrVPH9aOU4oqISyNtfJ4dz6t3ePWtPm5dcPw7ozmxoKr0TiutDUOuULQG0AEx4K/hdp@TqYGtwHGGtXhOs14wZ@T6uYqkcmivKP7YlneJi/Rngf7np5XpAfSI@np4OfBL32bH0CqSEvSJckPvY5/O/oZI2Us5lORM9hZeMUjFh9ZHphWMSCwjRyLyFIFntNM5qDrG4ypQtdW/GxFZDM57kGceQfaXvsNwkjUkfsB@@KoIZ3RYcw61aKYRhd85CZDtW@wk/yrbnqgzN9xkotU8owGnEKFjn/B@IS/IIbhGw)):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from heapq import merge

list_01 = ['DOG','CAT','BEAR']
list_02 = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']
list_03 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
lists = list_01, list_02, list_03
expect = ['DOG','V','A','CAT','W','B','BEAR','X','C','Y','D','Z','E','F','G','H']

result = list(map(itemgetter(1), merge(*map(enumerate, lists), key=itemgetter(0))))

print(result == expect)

index, value = map(itemgetter, (0, 1))
result = list(map(value, merge(*map(enumerate, lists), key=index)))

print(result == expect)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list_01 = ['DOG','CAT','BEAR']
list_02 = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']
list_03 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
L = [list_01, list_02, list_03]


def shuffle(L):
    result = []

    while any(L):
        for sub in L:
            if sub:
                result.append(sub.pop(0))

    return result

print(shuffle(L))
```

Output:

```
['DOG', 'V', 'A', 'CAT', 'W', 'B', 'BEAR', 'X', 'C', 'Y', 'D', 'Z', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

Comment: Do you mean without putting the sub lists into another list?

Comment: I have updated my sollution. I think the problem was that I removed from a List while iterating over it which created some nasty sideeffects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`more_itertools.interleave_longest`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_longest):

```py
>>> from more_itertools import interleave_longest
>>> list(interleave_longest(
...     ['DOG','CAT','BEAR'],
...     ['V','W','X','Y','Z'],
...     ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
... ))
['DOG', 'V', 'A', 'CAT', 'W', 'B', 'BEAR', 'X', 'C', 'Y', 'D', 'Z', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answers merges the lists in an unordered fashion, which is not exactly what OP wanted.

Use `itertools.chain` to chain the lists together into a single list, and then `random.shuffle` to shuffle this list in-place:

```
from itertools import chain
from random import shuffle

list_01 = ['DOG','CAT','BEAR']
list_02 = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']
list_03 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

full_list = list(chain(list_01, list_02, list_03))
shuffle(full_list)

print(full_list)  # in my case: ['BEAR', 'V', 'Z', 'W', 'A', 'Y', 'E', 'G', 'CAT', 'B', 'X', 'H', 'D', 'F', 'DOG', 'C']
```

Comment: The idea is not to shuffle them, but pick in order.

Comment: @AKX Ah, I see, I didn't get that from the question. Not sure if I should delete my answer but I'll at least edit it and add a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip function

```
list_01 = ['DOG','CAT','BEAR']
list_02 = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']
list_03 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

minimum_size = min(len(list_01) , len(list_02) , len(list_03))

new_array = []

for item1 , item2 , item3 in zip(list_01 , list_02 , list_03):
    new_array.extend([item1 , item2 , item3])
    
new_array += list_01[minimum_size:] + list_02[minimum_size:] + list_03[minimum_size:]

print(new_array)
```

Comment: It does not work correct of different length of lists

Answer (score 1):

By using plain python(without numpy), this is the best I could come up with.

I believe it works for any order, length of lists and does not assume fill_value

```py
list_01 = ['DOG','CAT','BEAR']
list_02 = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']
list_03 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
L = [list_01, list_03, list_02]
def zigzag(*arg):
    i = 0
    LL = []
    all_done = False
    while not all_done:
        all_done = True
        for l in arg:
            if i >= len(l):
                continue
            all_done = False
            LL.append(l[i])
        i += 1
    return LL
print(zigzag(list_01, list_02, list_03))
print(zigzag(list_01, list_03, list_02))
```